# Pulling score text data into r

Tags: r, text, import

Trying to figure out how to pull the following data into r:

http://masseyratings.com/scores.php?s=285971&sub=14342&all=1&mode=3&sch=on&format=0

This almost works, but I want to eliminate the junk on the top and bottom, and just get the scores.

```
read.fwf('http://masseyratings.com/scores.php?s=285971&sub=14342&all=1&mode=3&sch=on&format=0', 
         widths=c(11,26,3,26,3,4,21),  
         skip = 8)
```

Comment: what do you mean by junk at the top and bottom? It would be helpful if you could post a picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all welcome to stack exchange! So I changed somethings in your code such as you only needed 6 widths, you had an extra column so I got rid of that. When I was pulling in the data from online I noticed that the first row was pretty strange so I just got ride of it all together and then manually added it later.

```
data <- read.fwf('http://masseyratings.com/scores.php?s=285971&sub=14342&all=1&mode=3&sch=on&format=0',widths=c(10,26,3,26,3,4), sep = "\t", header = FALSE, skip = 8)
# This line subsets the data so you don't have that "junk" at the bottom and deletes the row
# with the html tagging. 

data <- data[2:2424,]
data <- data.frame(data)

# Create a vector that has the column headers
names <- c("date", "Team1","Runs", "Team 2","Runs","Something")
colnames(data) <- names

# Create the first row of data that we previously deleted.

firstrow = data.frame("2016-04-03", "@Pirates", 4, "Cardinals",1,"")
colnames(firstrow) <- names

finaldata <- rbind.data.frame(firstrow,data)
```

For future reference if you can post a screenshot of what you deem as junk that would be helpful for the people attempting to help you with your question.

**UPDATE**

```
data <- read.fwf('http://masseyratings.com/scores.php?s=285971&sub=14342&all=1&mode=3&sch=on&format=0',
                     widths=c(10,26,3,26,3,4), sep = "\t", header = FALSE, skip = 9)

data <- data.frame(data)

# This line subsets the data so you don't have that "junk" at the bottom and deletes the row
# with the html tagging. 

firstrow <- read.fwf('http://masseyratings.com/scores.php?s=285971&sub=14342&all=1&mode=3&sch=on&format=0',
                  widths=c(-8,-1,-1,9,26,3,26,3,4), sep = "\t", header = FALSE, n = 1, skip = 8)
firstrow <- data.frame(firstrow,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

firstrow[,1] <- paste("2",firstrow[1,1],sep = "")

# Create a vector that has the column headers
names <- c("date", "Team1","Runs", "Team 2","Runs","Something")
colnames(data) <- names



colnames(firstrow) <- names

finaldata <- rbind.data.frame(firstrow,data)
```

The negative values for the column with move the data over, I just played around with it until it worked out so that all that was missing in the first row was a "2". I then paste in the "2" and use the rbind function to create the full data frame. I hope that helps you out.

I tested it on this page as well: http://masseyratings.com/scores.php?s=285971&sub=14342&all=1&mode=2&sch=on&format=0
and it worked as expected.

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to not have to manually add first line back in, in the event that I want to pull data for multiple seasons, etc.?

Comment: @Fermat please see the update. I know it isn't the prettiest solution but it should answer your question. And if this works please click the check to mark it correct :)

Comment: @Fermat would love to get some feedback and know if this solution helped you.

Comment: @Fermat if you found the solution to be helpful, please accepted it as answer by clicking the check mark.